# Put some models out of the model.py to my created model.py?

Tags: python, django

In general, we start a app, then the app directory will like this:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

but, I now have a requirement, I want to add a module directory like this:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

I want to put the price's model in the price module directory.

Whether this is possible?

---

**EDIT**

I mean I want to separate some models form xxx_admin_product_config app's model.py file, and put to the red framework's model.py.

Comment: Can you explain why you want to do this?

Comment: I want to separate the models by a distinguished directory.

Answer (score 0):

You want to change the modele' place, but you must put them in the `django-admin startapp xxx` generated app directory's `model.py` file.

In your case, you should cd to your app directory(`xxx_admin_product_config`), then

```
django-admin startapp price
```

there will generate the price directory that contains the model.py.

you can put them there.

---

and you add the price app to the settings.py's `INSTALLED_APPS`:

```
xxx_admin_product_config.price
```

and `python manage.py makemigrate`, `python manage.py migrate` this should generate the models.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it, but what you can move may depend on the relationships between models.

For example, if you have a model class called `SomeModel` that exists in `xxx_admin_product_config/models.py`, then you can move that to `price/models.py` and import it.

```
# xxx_admin_product_config/models.py 

from .price.models import SomeModel
```

Be aware of circular imports. If `SomeModel` depended upon something in `xxx_admin_product_config/models.py` that wouldn't work, and you'd have to do some restructuring.

Comment: @sof-03 - did this answer help you?